# Expectation of the sum of N Poisson r.v.

Tags: probability, proof-verification, expectation, generating-functions

> Let $N, X_1, X_2, . . .$ be independent random variables such that $N ∈ Pois(1)$ and $X_k ∈ Pois(2)$ for all $k$. Set $Z = \sum_{k=1}^{N}X_k$ (and $Z = 0$ when $N = 0$). Compute $E(Z), Var(Z),$ and $P(Z = 0)$.

So, $X_k$ and $N$ are Poisson r.v. $f(X_k=k)=e^{-1}\frac{1}{k!}$; $f(N=k)=e^{-2}\frac{2}{k!}$.

Probability generating functions:

$g_{z}(t)=g_n(g_x(t))$, where $g_x(t)=e^{-1}\sum_{k=0}t^k/k!=e^{-1+t}$,$g_n(t)=2e^{-2}\sum_{k=0}t^k/k!=2e^{-2+t}$

So, $g_z(t)=2e^{-2+e^{-1+t}}$, now $E(Z)=\frac{dg_z(t)}{dt}$ at $t=1$;
$\frac{dg_z(t)}{dt}=2e^{e^{t-1}+t-3}$ and at $t=1$, I recieve $E(Z)=2e^{1-2}$

the answer is $E(Z)=2$

Can you help me? What is wrong in the computations? Also $P(Z=k)=\frac{g_z^k(t)}{k!}$ is this right?

Comment: I know also that $E(Z)=E(N)E(X)=2$, but I want to find the expectation the way I wrote.

Comment: How did you compute the derivative?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch $dg_z(t)/dt=2e^{e^{t-1}-2}=2e^{e^{t-1}-2}\frac{de^{t-1}-2}{dt}=2e^{e^{t-1}-2}(e^{t-1} (t-1)'+(-2)')=2e^{e^{t-1}+t-3}$

Comment: I think there is just an error in the probability generating function of $N$ (ie $g_n$)

Comment: Right, because it is $P(N = k) = e^{-2} 2^k/k!$ and not $P(N = k) = e^{-2} 2/k!$.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!!

Comment: But also, your question states $X_k \in Pois(2)$ and $N \in Pois(1)$, but you calculated with the reversed assumptions. You might want to clarify this.